# altova xml spy 2009: result-document always lands in temp folder

Tags: xslt, altova

I am generating result-documents from within my XSL script. However, they are always saved in my temp folder. Does anyone happen to know, where I can configure that?

Comment: I don't use Altova XML Spy but you might want to show your code and explain whether both absolute URls (`file:///C:/dir/subdir/result.xml`) as well as relative URIs (`result.xml`) end up in that folder.

Comment: the absolute uri did the trick, thanks a lot (once again :D )! it even creates the folder. how did you know that would make a difference? experience from other IDEs or does that have to do with xsl?

Comment: Well if an absolute URI would end up in that temp folder the I would say that is a bug as `xsl:result-document` is specified http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees. You might want to ask in an Altova XML Spy forum whether and if so how it allows you to set the base output URI http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-base-output-uri so that your relative URIs are resolved to a different directory.